# Powershell Get-AdUser Manager getting null value for Users who have managers

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get a list of users from Active Directory written out to an xml file to send to a 3rd part vendor for an integration.

I have the following function in powershell the grabs said user info and builds the elenment

```
function Write-ManagerElement() {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Builds the Manager XML Element 
.DESCRIPTION
Builds the Manager XML Element
.EXAMPLE
Write-ManagerElement -user 'jdoe'
.PARAMETER $writer - xml writer
.PARAMETER $server - AD Domain Controller
.PARAMETER $user - Passed user
#>
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][System.Xml.XmlTextWriter]$writer = $xmlWriter,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$server = $env:DomainControllerServer,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][System.Object]$user
    )

    $writer.WriteStartElement('manager')
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($user.Manager)) {
        $manager = Get-AdUser -Identity $user.Manager -Server $server -Credential $credential -Properties DistinguishedName, objectGUID
        $writer.WriteAttributeString('uid', $manager.ObjectGUID.ToString())
        $writer.WriteAttributeString('dn', $manager.DistinguishedName)
    } else {
        $writer.WriteAttributeString('uid', '')
        $writer.WriteAttributeString('dn', '')
    }
    $writer.WriteEndElement()
}
```

I have also successfully using the following bit in place and it also worked

```
$manager = (Get-ADUser (Get-ADUser $user -Properties manager -Server $env:DomainControllerServer -Credential $credential).manager -Server
```

Both methods run fine in the test environment (which no way mirrors our Prod) but for 76 users it says that $user.Manager is not null but can't seem to get the value back seems to be returning a null. Anyone have any ideas on what I am missing?

So after using the following

```
foreach($user in $users) {
    "Processing $($user)"
    $usr = Get-ADUser -Identity $user -Server $env:DomainControllerServer -Credential $credential -Properties *
    $manager = Get-ADUser -Identity $usr.Manager -Server $env:DomainControllerServer -Credential $credential -Properties *
    "$($user) -> $($usr.DisplayName) -> $($manager.DisplayName)"
    $usr = $null
    $manager = $null
}
```

It seems as though the problem occurs when a User has a Management group as opposed to a single user manager

Comment: Hard to say....your explanation is a bit vague. Whats the output for "Get-ADUser username -Properties Manager | ft samaccountname, manager"? Do you get a result? You can check also for a null-value like this: "(Get-ADUser username -Properties Manager).Manager -eq $null)". You may also miss the corresponding access rights to those userobjects.

Comment: @Tom I will check your suggestions, I unfortunately I have to wait until some who has access to our PROD ad can assist. Will report back on both those key pieces of info once I have them

Comment: @tom so it seems that all the items are returning null via the powershell Applet using the code you suggested. Looking in ActiveDirectiry against the users we tested fell into two types: 1. Some have a group of Managers assigned and 2. Some have a single user assigned. But the Get-AdUser returns null for all the user managers we tried

Comment: maybe you should try and use `Get-ADObject` instead of `Get-ADUser` for the manager part, since it can be either a user or a group of users and/or groups. If it is a group, you need to get the groupmembers of that group recursively. You know if it is a group by looking at the `.ObjectClass` property of the returned object from Get-ADObject. ("group" for a group and "user" when it is a user). For a group you output the **Name** property. For a user you can use the **DisplayName** property

Comment: @Theo will give that a shot thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Weird. According to this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676859(v=vs.85).aspx the manager attribute is single-valued and is the distinguished name of a user object iirc. So it should not be possible to add groups or multiple entries to this value . But still - @Theo might be on the right track. If somehow those are not user objects you should get a result. But it wont help you if you have multiple values because -identity only takes one value. You need to do something like this $user.manager | %{Get-Adobject -identity $_ [...]}

Comment: After some more research the reason for this is we are using Quest and ASR so the in order to get what we I need I have to switch to their powershell module